# Programming Attiny45 using Arduino Uno with weird behavior

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, battery

I bought an Arduino Uno a few days ago.

I programmed an ATtiny45 using an Arduino Uno following "How-To: Shrinkify Your Arduino Projects" video on YouTube.

I uploaded the blink example successfully. I altered the sketch in a way so there is also a blinking on pin 4 (which is ATtiny45 pin 3).

Now, if I connect +5V from the Arduino to ATtiny45 pin 8, ground to pin 4 and the LEDs from pin 2 and 3 to ground everything works as expected.

But if I use 4 AA batteries instead of the power from the Arduino I only get a blinking on ATtiny pin2.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Is it because I use 4 AA -> 6 V instead of 5 V? I tested it also with 3 AA batteries and got the same result.

So why does it work if I use power and ground from the Arduino but not from the batteries?

Comment: I just used 2 AA batteries and it worked fine.

Comment: 6V is no problem for the Uno.  It likes 7-9 volts better (to keep the regulator chip cool) but can go from 5-12 volts.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at Attiny45 [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2586-avr-8-bit-microcontroller-attiny25-attiny45-attiny85_datasheet.pdf), you will find at the very first page:

> Operating Voltage
>
> - 1.8 - 5.5V for ATtiny25V/45V/85V
> - 2.7 - 5.5V for ATtiny25/45/85

Your circuit will have unpredictable behavior out of this range. If you want to use four AA cels, you can organize them to have a 3V output or use a step-down voltage regulator.